# Combining data files with Querying? Manual Coding, Xml or SQL from VB.NEt

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am looking to combine huge CSV file together (+150 megs x9), apply a simple query and remove data from the archive, and repeat the exercise. I don't know much about SQL yet, thus I have stayed from it(time has always been a factor). However with large Excel documents > 1 gig. which take forever to load and edit, I am rethinking my approach. I would like to do something in VB.Net

I have rather enjoyed the XML database system, however not sure how it is going to cope with copious amounts of data?? Something I might test if I don't get any feedback.

My question would be is it possible to package in a single exe, a SQLCE database, with type of functionality?

It is something I can manually code into memory, but then the querying I would have to manually code the process as well.

Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: So you want to load your CSV in memory as a data table, run some queries on it and pack it into another CSV file?

Comment: SQL Express would be a better choice than CE. Look into NoSQL.  Look into BULK load options for whatever DB you choose. XML would probably not be a good idea. Eval ninja-net-database or similar http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-43-ninja-net-database-pro.aspx

Comment: Thanks Guys, I will have a look at express. Can you package express? 

    The idea is N x *.csv -> Query -> sort -> Output.xls